# Get azure b2c custom claims in angular application

Tags: azure, azure-ad-b2c

I have custom claim say email . I use hello js to login from a angular app.

```
var authResponse = hello(helloNetwork.adB2CSignInSignUp).getAuthResponse();
```

The above code gives me the token but i am not getting the email claim that i have added.

How can I get the custom claim that i have configured .

Answer (score 0):

In order to get custom claims, you need to edit the policy and select "Email address" under the Application Claims blade. (See image in link below)

Please verify that is enabled for the policy that you are calling. If you have it enabled and it still doing that, can you please send a screenshot of the portal and a resulting token (that does not have the email address claim).

[Screenshot of azure portal](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XG0JO.png)